# YTPlayerView customize buttons to start stop

Tags: ios, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api, ytplayerview

I am using `YTPlayerView` to play YouTube videos inside my app. I need to do some customization that instead of using `YTPlayerView` button I want to create my own buttons to control the playing view and also I want to handle it by my self that when the video will go to full screen.

I know that we can also use `UIWebView`. I there is some way that I can do the same thing using `UIWebView` then I can also do that.

Is there any way that I can do this or YouTube is providing a common way to play videos which we see in many other applications.

Answer (score 0):

So what exactly is your question?  Are you looking to create you own buttons to start the video, stop the video, and make the video full screen?

```
YTPlayerView *playerView = ...

// ...

- (IBAction)playButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [playerView playVideo];
}

- (IBAction)pauseButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [playerView pauseVideo];
}

- (IBAction)stopButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [playerView playVideo];
}
```

There is a discussion on the GitHub page about playing a video full screen programmatically: https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/35

Comment: But how i can remove the default buttons that YTPlayerView adds?

Comment: So the question is that how i can remove the default play/pause button and adds my own button that does the same job? This is because of many reasons, i want to have a different play pause buttons. Does YTPlayerView exposes such kind of properties like buttons etc. I have searched it and figured out that it uses UIWebView which is embedded in in YTPlayerView API.

Comment: What do you mean the default buttons?  Do you mean the buttons in the video player?  No, there is no way to override those, that player is on the iOS system level.  You could make the player so that any touches in the player don't show the controls but pause the video and use your own buttons.  You could also override any touches to the player and disable interaction with the player, but that would break YouTube's Terms of Service.

Comment: Okay so actually if i have to play YT videos in my app then i have to use their default player. right?